# I'm getting issue while for each the nested array

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, foreach

**Given Array**

```
         Array
    (
        [status] => 1
        [error] => 0
        [list] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [name] => Bandtoer
                        [data] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => OVERLAND
                                [1] => DETAIN
                                [2] => OVERNIGHT
                            )
    
                        [origin] => 1
                        [destination] => 1
                    )
          )


)
```

**Want to display all the array**

**Code**

```
foreach ($response as $list => $val) {
    foreach ($list as $atr => $val2) {
       echo $list;
      foreach ($atr as $atr1 => $val3) {
        echo $atr1 . ":" . $val3 . ":";
        }
    }
}
```

I mean to display these nested array but could not so far, I am also getting the error **Illegal string offset** please help me where I am going wrong

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do but I think this might help -
`$list = $response['list'];
foreach ($list as $val) {}`

Comment: Hi thanks for answering let me explain you i want to display this array with the help of for each and im trying to do that and couldnt do so far if u could help me

Answer (score 0):

Please check the foreach syntax. Foreach iterates the array item using $key and $val format. $key could be integer or string index.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

In the nested foreach, you are trying to loop through a key which cannot be an array at any instance